# Why carriers move when Electric field is applied on Haynes-Shockley experiment

Tags: semiconductors, materials, solid-state-devices

I would like to know why excess carriers/minority move when an electric field is applied at the Haynes-Shockley expirement

[image]

Comment: @Transistor I think  "carriers" is the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because charge in field feels force equal to field times charge. Coulomb law. The interesting question is why don't those charges accelerate to very high speeds. This is because they statistically hit the lattice atoms, then start all over. This is the mean free path.

Comment: So holes (aka e-) moves to the positive charge as natural ?
and vise versa

Comment: Yes. But when you look really closely, you notice that a movement of a hole leftward is in fact movement of en electron rightward.

Comment: yes, holes move one way and electrons the other ,usually faster.
Also It's (aka p+), holes are positive charged